# Operations on a vector

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I have the following class which is used for operations on a vector. The vector stores the following struct which has 3 enums and 1 boolean.

Info represents a computer node. Nodes communicate with each other. Some nodes are unique (in which case they don't have an ID (and others are not so they have a id associated with them. `InfoIdEnum` basically is `{one,two,three,four}`. When nodes send each other a message, the `info_discovered` becomes true. Also, some objects send others information when their `state` changes. Not all objects talk to each other.

```
struct Info
{
    InfoEnum info_name;
    InfoIdEnum info_id;
    InfoStatesEnum info_state;
    bool info_discovered = false;
};
```

The operations on the vector include checking if `info_discovered` was received for an element having the same `info_name` and `info_id` and also returning the `InfoStatesEnum` for the same case.

I wrote the following functions to implement this:

```
///Second is optional parameter. Some InfoEnum don't need an ID with them
bool findInfoElement(Info * info,const InfoEnum info_name,const InfoIdEnum info_id=InfoIdEnum::NONE) const 
{
    ///m_info_vector is the vector
    if(m_info_vector.empty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    /// Iterate through elements to find a match
    for(Info node_info : m_info_vector)
    {
        if(node_info.info_name == info_name &&
           node_info.info_id == info_id )
        {
            *info = node_info;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is where it is used in the same class:

```
bool isNodeDiscovered(const InfoEnum name,const InfoIdEnum id=InfoIdEnum::NONE) const
{
    Info node;
    if(findInfoElement(&node, name,id))
    {
        if(node.info_discovered)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And to add a new element if it doesn't exist and update the existing if it exists:

```
void updateInformation(const Info node_info)
{
    if(m_info_vector.empty())
    {
        m_info_vector.push_back(node_info);
        return;
    }
    /// Iterate through nodes to find a match
    for(Info info : m_info_vector)
    {
        if(info.info_name == node_info.info_name &&
           info.info_id == node_info.info_id    )
        {
            /// Node already present,update the values
            info = node_info;
            return;

        }
    }
    ///Not Empty but doesn't contain the value.
    m_info_vector.push_back(node_info);
}
```

I am worried if there is any potential pitfall I should be aware of in the code / way to optimize it for performance if the vector size is guaranteed to be fewer than 16 elements.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are trying to achieve with this code. Is this real code from one of your projects? If so, could you explain more what an `Info` represents, and show us the entire class?

Comment: that's all the class contains.3 functions and a private m_info_vector.

Comment: Then can you [edit] the question to clarify what an `Info` represents?

Comment: Info represents an object.Objects communicate with each other .Some objects are unique(in which case they don't have an Id) and others are not so they have a id associated with them. InfoIdEnum basically is {one,two,three,four}. When objects send each other a message, the info discovered becomes true.Also some objects send others information when their state changes. Not all objects talk to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Names

Just for example, `Info` is *much* too generic a name. Although you haven't said much about what exact sort of info this is, you should rename it to reflect the kind of info being stored.

#### Data Structures

As long as you're *sure* you'll never store more than 16 items, I suppose it's reasonable to use a `vector` and use linear searching to find items. If there's any possibility of more items, I'd switch to something like a `map` or `set`. Even as it stands now, I'd *consider* using a `map` or `unordered_map` anyway, simply because it directly supports so many of the things you want/need to do.

#### Top-level `const`:

Consider the parameters to your `isNodeDiscovered`:

```
bool isNodeDiscovered(const InfoEnum name,const InfoIdEnum id=InfoIdEnum::NONE)
```

You're passing these by value, so the `const` doesn't really mean or accomplish anything and might as well be removed:

```
bool isNodeDiscovered(InfoEnum name, InfoIdEnum id=InfoIdEnum::NONE)
```

Note that this is *not* the case when the `const` applies to something to which you're passing a reference or pointer. There the `const` can mean a lot and shouldn't be removed with impunity.

#### Encapsulation

Since you have a specific idea of how one `Info` object should be compared to another for equality, I'd encode that into the `Info` object itself:

```
bool Info::operator==(Info const &other) const { 
    return info_name == other.info_name && info_id == other.info_id;
}
```

This lets you use standard algorithms to implement most of your other operations:

```
bool find_info_element(Info *info, InfoEnum info_name, InfoIdEnum info_id=InfoIdEnum::NONE) {
    Info i { info_name, info_id};
    auto pos = std::find(m_info_vector.begin(), m_info_vector.end(), i);
    if (pos == m_info_vector.end())
        return false;
    *info = *pos;
    return true;
}
```

I'd at least consider changing this to just return the iterator though--that would be much more in keeping with how things are typically done in C++.

#### Using map

As mentioned previously, using `std::map` (or `unordered_map`) would simplify the code quite a bit--to the point that I'm tempted to recommend using it, even though it's sort of overkill for just 16 elements. To do this, we'd start by separating an `Info` into the part that acts as the key and the data that's stored with that key:

```
typedef std::pair<InfoEnum, InfoIdEnum> Key;

class Data {
    InfoStatesEnum info_state;
    bool info_discovered = false;
};
```

Then we'd define a `map` of that type:

```
std::map<key, data> info_data;
```

Then (for example) `updateInformation` would become something like this:

```
void updateInformation(Key const &key, Data const &data)
{
    info_data[key] = data;
}
```

Another possibility would be to use a class that provided the same interface as a `map`, but stored its data in a `vector`. For one example, Boost's [`flat_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html) does exactly this.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent feedback. Using Iterators and refactoring to use Maps sounds a lot better than my current implementation.